# How is come around different from just coming?

Tags: phrase-usage

For these two expressions

> Some of my friends will **come at 6** in the evening.
>
> Some of my friends will **come around at** 6 in the evening.

I would like to know if these two expression differ in meaning? Does adding around change the meaning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version with *come* is a bit more formal, and implies that your friends are coming specifically to visit, or at least that the main purpose of their trip is to come to your house (to be at your party, to play poker, to have dinner, to watch the big sporting event, etc.).

The version with *come around* is more informal, and implies that their visit to you may be only one portion of their outing, and possibly quite brief or minor; they may intend to go see a movie, or eat at a restaurant, or some other thing, after they have stopped to visit you for a while.  Indeed, they could be "coming around" simply to pick you up to go with them.

Comment: So just plain *come* would be like *arrive* or maybe *show up*, while *come around* would be like *stop over*.

Answer (score 3):

*Around* adds a degree of informality and approximation to the second that is lacking in the first.

Comment: Informality, yes, but approximation would more likely be expressed as "will come at around 6".  To me, "come around" in this sense is equivalent to "come by" or "drop in".  (Bias: northeast U.S.)

Comment: @barbara beeton. That is true, but the informality of _come around_ itself suggests a less than precise hour.

Comment: I guess we differ here.  I agree about the imprecision, but to me, it has nothing to do with time, more with whether the visitors will arrive at all.